# How can I convert .tar to .tgz

Tags: python, subprocess, gzip, tar

I'm trying to compress some files with python. I'm using subprocess, the problem is that I don't know how to compress all the files. Here is what I do:

```
comand = czf
saveFolder = /home/albert/a.tgz
temporal = /home/albert/test1

subprocess.call(["tar",comand,saveFolder,temporal])
```

How can I add more files? If i try to do this, it sends me error:

```
subprocess.call(["tar",comand,saveFolder,temporal1,temporal2])

subprocess.call(["tar",comand,saveFolder,temporal + temporal2])
```

I also tryed to use:

```
subprocess.call(["tar",comand,saveFolder,temporal])
```

and then add all files into the .tar file

```
subprocess.call(["tar","rvf",saveFolder,temporal])
```

The problem with that last idea is that I can just do it for .tar files, but with .gzip or other types it doesn't work.

What I can do? 
Thanks.

Comment: Could you perhaps add all the files with it being a tar file (no z during the create step), then gzip it at the end when you know you're done adding files to the archive?

Comment: the code is not a valid Python. "sends me error" is not informative. Provide the full traceback. `check_call(["tar", "czf", "a.tgz", "test1", "test2"])` works as is  -- it creates the compressed archive with `test1`, `test2` files in it. If you want absolute names (you don't in most cases), use `--absolute-names` option.

Comment: How I can transform into a gzip after it is a .tar with all files?

Comment: @user2911701: the option `z` in your question already creates a compressed archive. If it is not related to your current question then don't put it in a comment, [ask a new question instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) Though [@Sylvain Leroux already answered it: use `gzip`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29375196/4279)

Answer (score 2):

What if you use only Python to do the dirty job?

**Creating a tar package from entire dir (not compressed)**

```
>>> import tarfile
>>> tar = tarfile.open('package.tar', 'w')
>>> tar.add('full/path/of/dir/')
>>> tar.close()
```

**Updating a tar package.**

Obs.: You can't update compressed package. It must be decompressed, updated, them re-compressed

```
>>> tar = tarfile.open('package.tar', 'w')
>>> tar.add('new_file.txt')
>>> tar.add('new_other_file.txt')
>>> tar.close()
```

**Creating a tar package compressed**

```
>>> tar = tarfile.open('package.tar.gz', 'w:gz')
>>> tar.add('server.db')
>>> tar.add('readme.txt')
>>> tar.close()
```

Comment: I need to use Bash command. It's work for college, i need to use subprocess with the tar commands

Comment: Ok, understood. Anyway, when you need to solve real problems, here is a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

`tgz` files are only gzipped tar archives. And shortcut for `.tar.gz`.

- You can create and compress an archive using `tar cz`
- You can create a (non compressed) archive using `tar c`
- You can append to a (non compressed) archive using `tar r` or `tar u` (see the man for the difference)
- You can use `gzip` to compress the archive.
- But, you cannot (at least with GNU tar) update a compressed archive.